# How to load page with category option pre-selected

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to send links to this web application with a category option pre-selected. Is it possible to include it in the URL or just have one/multiple options preselected when linking someone?

**PLEASE NOTE:** Adding the "checked" attribute in this case will not work, it shows the checkbox as being selected but when you load the page the products from that category are not visible.

```
<div class="filterTitle" style="padding-left: 5px">Choose subject(s)</div>

<div class="filterctn">
 <div class="optionctn">
  <input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="accounting" id="accounting">
  <label class="filterlabel" for="accounting">Accounting</label>
 </div>     
</div>
```

Comment: So you call the code that runs and shows the next step

Comment: Well, apparently there's some code that runs when one of the checkboxes are checked. We can't know what that is unless you share it with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to programmatically call the method to load the products from that category.
If you do not have access to that method, you could trigger click event on specific checkbox once the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `checked` attribute:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="agriculture" id="agriculture" checked>
```

Comment: That shows the checkbox as "checked" but doesn't actually select it and the products from that category do not show up like that.

Comment: @bicycle4431 you will need to dynamically handle this with javascript and have the server-side parse the URL and query string